# How to fix error in node.js when I trying to handle subdomais

Tags: node.js, express, routes

When I am using `domainRouting` function, then if I am using `res.send` in routes file then everything is working. When I want to show view for some reason that I dont know when I run `npm start` it starts normaly, but when I visit that website in browser then I don't know why, but I am getting error, and server crashes.

> “Cannot GET /“

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
var login = require('./routes/login');

function domainRouting(req, res, next){
    var subdomain = req.headers.host.split('.')[0];

    if(subdomain === 'login'){
        login(req, res, next);
    };
    if(subdomain === 'equestriansnet'){
        appRoutes(req, res, next);
    }
   next();
};

var app = express();
var connection = 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:slaptas@147.135.210.148:27017/d', { auth: { authdb: 'admin' } });
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});




app.use('*', domainRouting);
//app.use('/', appRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
//app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//  res.render('index');
//});

module.exports = app;
```

(db pass is random word just for hiding real-one) and one of my route files 
that points one of **subdomains**

```
var express   = require('express');
var router    = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //res.render('index');
    res.send('Main ' + req.url);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I founded problem. It`s this line of code

```
 next();
```

if I put this in if then everything will work correct.